# Returned JSON File From TEXT_DETECTION Is Not Properly Formatted

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I followed Google's documentation for their Vision API to write a program that runs TEXT_DETECTION on an image. Unlike the documentation and Google Vision the tester on their website which returns a properly formatted JSON, the JSON file I get in return is missing commas in between Objects and is missing brackets for JSONArrays.

I use the following line to get the JSON response.

```
BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
```

Here is my code for the TEXT_DETECTION.

```
    public static final Type SEARCH_TYPE = Type.TEXT_DETECTION;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        try (ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
            String fileName = "resources/testPic.jpg";

            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);
            List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
            Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
            Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(SEARCH_TYPE).build();
            AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
            requests.add(request);

            BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
            List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();
```

Here is a snippet of what my responses look like from BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.

```
 text_annotations {
    description: "almora"
    bounding_poly {
      vertices {
        x: 2307
        y: 713
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2480
        y: 711
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2480
        y: 727
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2307
        y: 729
      }
    }
  }
  text_annotations {
    description: "ryan"
    bounding_poly {
      vertices {
        x: 2458
        y: 906
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2489
        y: 933
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2476
        y: 947
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2446
        y: 920
      }
    }
  }
  text_annotations {
    description: "flanco"
    bounding_poly {
      vertices {
        x: 2441
        y: 890
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2458
        y: 905
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2443
        y: 922
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2426
        y: 907
      }
    }
  }
  text_annotations {
    description: "garbanzo beans"
    bounding_poly {
      vertices {
        x: 3780
        y: 1051
      }
      vertices {
        x: 3824
        y: 1050
      }
      vertices {
        x: 3824
        y: 1063
      }
      vertices {
        x: 3780
        y: 1064
      }
    }
  }
  text_annotations {
    description: "roberto"
    bounding_poly {
      vertices {
        x: 2111
        y: 906
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2163
        y: 905
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2163
        y: 920
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2111
        y: 921
      }
    }
  }
  text_annotations {
    description: "A10"
    bounding_poly {
      vertices {
        x: 2398
        y: 935
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2442
        y: 972
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2424
        y: 994
      }
      vertices {
        x: 2380
        y: 956
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I change it or fix it so that the returned file is a properly formatted JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

When using annotate, there is no json file. The response is a BatchAnnotateImagesResponse object.

If you want to generate a json file, you can use [asyncBatchAnnotate](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/asyncBatchAnnotate) instead. asyncBatchAnnotate writes json files to your gcs bucket when it finishes.

Comment: Thank you, I am now using BatchAnnotateImagesResponse and then download the JSON file from the bucket. Do you know if it's possible to run BatchAnnotateImagesResponse on several images in the bucket at the same time?

Comment: And they could all be in a single directory?

Comment: Yes, you can run asyncBatchAnnotate on several images at the same time, by adding another request to the list. The images can be in any bucket you have access to.

Comment: The images can be in the same directory. You have to specify each image explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

`com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat.printer().print(responses)`

after

`List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();`

This will give you JSON string for your response object.